# How to throw a catchable error that displays concisely

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-core

I'd like to throw an error from a custom cmdlet that

1. Is *script*-terminating, causing any script it is part of to terminate (unless caught)
2. Displays concisely if shown in a terminal, without a stack trace

So far I have tried:

| Description (with screenshot) | Script-terminating | Concise | Catchable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [`throw` statement on a naked string.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKpOS.png) | ✅ Yes | ❌ No | ✅ Yes |
| [The `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError` method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVxZY.png) | ❌ No | ✅ Yes | ✅ Yes |
| [The `Write-Error` cmdlet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViqS9.png) | ❌ No *(nor statement-terminating)* | ✅ Yes | ❌ No |

Note that my cmdlet should be usable from scripts not controlled by me too - that is, the behavior shouldn't require setting preference variables if doing so would affect the running script.

Is there any way to throw a concise/informative error from a cmdlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for a [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw) statement to generate a *single-line* error message *without a location message* - assuming that the [`$ErrorView` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#errorview) is at its (PowerShell (Core)) default, `'Concise'` -
is:

- You must be running [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (as your tags incidate) rather than the legacy *Windows PowerShell* edition...
- ... *and* the (cmdlet-like) function that uses `throw` must originate from a (persisted)<sup>[1]</sup> PowerShell [*module*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules).

*Caveats*:

- Unlike when you use `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()` (which only generates a *statement*-terminating error, however), the exception message will be prefixed generically with `Exception:` rather than the *function name*.
  This applies up to at least PowerShell 7.3.7 (current as of this writing).
- By using `throw`, your cmdlet-like function will exhibit nonstandard behavior, given that *binary* cmdlets (those compiled into .NET assemblies) can *not* generate *script*-terminating errors, only *statement*-terminating ones.

---

<sup>[1] Curiously, this does *not* apply to *dynamic* modules created via [`New-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`Write-Error` is non-terminating in your case, because `$ErrorActionPreference` is by default set to `Continue`. If you change it: `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`, it'll terminate.

Another way to change `Write-Error` behaviour is to add `ErrorAction` parameter: `Write-Error 'foobar' -ErrorAction Stop`. It'll terminate regardless of `$ErrorAction` setting.

To control the way errors are displayed in a terminal, take a look at [$ErrorView Preference Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3#errorview). If you use `DetailedView`, both `throw` and `Write-Error` will be displayed across multiple lines. `ConciseView` made available in Powershell 7 is probably the one you want based on your question. It's single line with message only when error comes from the terminal or module, and more lines if it's from a script.
Another viable option is `CategoryView`: there's more information, but always single line.